# Why does the index is out of range?

Tags: java, linked-list

```java
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class GamesChallenge {

    private static LinkedList<Game> gameList = new LinkedList<>();

    public static void main(String[] args){

        //adding the games to the LinkedList

        addGame("Call of Duty", 300);
        addGame("Last day on Earth", 500);
        addGame("Fall Guys", 3000);
        System.out.println(gameList);

        //try to find the game in the LinkedList
        findGame("Fall Guys");

        //try to remove a game
        removeGame("Fall Guys");
        System.out.println(gameList);

    }

    public static void addGame(String name, int memory){
        // check if the song is in the linkedList
        Game game = new Game(name, memory);
        while(findGame(name) == false){
            //if the game does not exist then the game is added
            gameList.add(game);
            break;
        }

    }

    public static boolean findGame(String name){
        // check if the game is in the LinkedList
        if(gameList.indexOf(gameList.contains(name)) >= 0){
            //if the index is bigger or equal to 0 (the game is in the LinkedList) then it will return true
            return true;
        }
        //else it will return false
        else return false;
    }

 //here is where I have the problem
 
 public static void removeGame(String name){
     gameList.remove(gameList.indexOf(gameList.contains(name)));
 
 }
}


class Game {

    private String name;
    private int memory;

    public Game(String name, int memory){
        this.name = name;
        this.memory = memory;

    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return name + ":" + memory;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getMemory() {
        return memory;
    }
}
```

I am new to programming and i am trying to learn. I tried to remove the game from the LinkedList but an error is thrown, the index is out of range and I do not understand why.

Comment: Please edit your post adding debugging details such as error message you got during compilation or runtime and also improved the formatting of the text. Reading [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) will help you to edit your post

Comment: Fix your code formatting. Either indent all lines four spaces, or wrap in a pair of triple back-ticks.

Comment: Is it your intention to use the _LinkedList_ class specifically, or would an alternate collection type suffice?

Comment: `gameList.remove(gameList.indexOf(gameList.contains(name)))` doesn't begin to make sense. `contains()` returns a boolean, and your list doesn't contain booleans, and even if it did you don't need to search the list twice. What you appear to mean is simply `gameList.remove(gameList.indexOf(name))`. And you don't need a `while` loop when inserting.

Comment: For your code `ArrayList` is the better choice (in fact, there are hardly any reasons to use `LinkedList`; it generally has worse memory use **and** worse performance).

Comment: @MarkRotteveel thank you for the comment. This is an exercise from a course I am taking so this was just a way for me to learn how to use LinkedLists.

Comment: @Reilas i wanted to use the LinkedList class because this is just an exercise from the course I am taking.

Answer (score 0):

`gameList.contains(name)` returns a boolean indicating whether or not `name` is found in the `List`. Calling `gameList.indexOf` on that boolean will **always** return -1 because a `Game` object is never equal to a boolean.

You can instead use `List#removeIf` to remove based on the condition of the name of the game being equal to the parameter.

```java
public static void removeGame(String name){
    gameList.removeIf(g -> g.getName().equals(name));
}
```

The other methods are also implemented erroneously, having similar issues. You could use streams or an enhanced for loop to check for a game with a matching name.

```java
public static boolean findGame(String name){
    return gameList.stream().anyMatch(g -> g.getName().equals(name));
}
public static void addGame(String name, int memory){
    if (!findGame(name))
        gameList.add(new Game(name, memory));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Problem:**

```
gameList.contains(name)
```

returns true or false

```
gameList.indexOf(gameList.contains(name))
```

you are trying to find index of a boolean which returns -1.

And you are trying to remove value at -1 index hence getting IndexOutBoundException.

**Solution:**

Apart from above problem I found several other problems. So sharing working code. You'll find

***"// --- Modified:"*** comments with description where ever I've made changes

```
class GamesChallenge {

private static LinkedList<Game> gameList = new LinkedList<>();


public static void addGame(String name, int memory){
    // check if the song is in the linkedList
    Game game = new Game(name, memory);
    // --- Modified: Removed while loop as it is unecessary
    //  and modified condition to check index
    if(findGame(name) == -1){
        //if the game does not exist then the game is added
        gameList.add(game);
    }

}

public static void removeGame(String name){
    // --- Modified: We check the index and then 
    //  perform remove operation
    int index = findGame(name);
    if(index >= 0)
        gameList.remove(index);
}

public static int findGame(String name){
    // --- Modified: You are storing objects in linkedlist 
    // so to find index yoy have to pass the object reference.
    // I've simplified this method
    
    // Loop through all the element
    for(int i = 0; i < gameList.size(); i++){
        // check if name matches then return index
        if(gameList.get(i).getName().contains(name))
            return i;
    }
    return -1;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    //adding the games to the LinkedList

    addGame("Call of Duty", 300);
    addGame("Last day on Earth", 500);
    addGame("Fall Guys", 3000);
    System.out.println(gameList);

    //try to find the game in the LinkedList
    findGame("Fall Guys");

    //try to remove a game
    removeGame("Fall Guys");
    System.out.println(gameList);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally, either [contains(Game g)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/LinkedList.html#contains(java.lang.Object)) or [indexOf(Game g)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/LinkedList.html#indexOf(java.lang.Object)) is needed. If you need to know where in the [LinkedList](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/LinkedList.html) (or any [List](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html)) the item is, use `indexOf`. If you only need to know if the item is in the List, use `contains`. Per the language docs, if the `Object` (`Game`, in this case) is not in the list, `contains` returns `false` while `indexOf` returns `-1`.

Importantly, both methods use [Objects.equals](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Objects.html#equals(java.lang.Object,java.lang.Object)), which uses `Game.equals` in turn. Since `Game` does not override the inherited `Object.equals`, neither `contains` nor `indexOf` will work as expected here. (Note that overriding equals has additional requirements, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2265637/4407486)).

Finally, `contains(String name)` on a `List<Game>` will always* return false since a `Game` can not be equal to a `String`.

**There is an edge case if both values are `null` that may yield different results.*

Answer (score -1):

If I run your code, I get the following output.

```
[Call of Duty:300, Last day on Earth:500, Fall Guys:3000]
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: -1, Size: 3
    at java.base/java.util.LinkedList.checkElementIndex(LinkedList.java:559)
    at java.base/java.util.LinkedList.remove(LinkedList.java:529)
    at GamesChallenge.removeGame(GamesChallenge.java:49)
    at GamesChallenge.main(GamesChallenge.java:20)
```

The *[stack-trace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_trace#Java)* here shows that the last instruction from the *GamesChallenge* class, was the *removeGame* method call.

In which, on line 49 had made a call to *LinkedList#remove*.

```java
gameList.remove(gameList.indexOf(gameList.contains(name)));
```

It appears that you are trying to locate a value with *gameList*, and if it exists, remove it.

Since the *removeGame* has a *name* parameter, you'll need to iterate on *gameList*, and remove the match.
Note, this will remove only the first match.
Remove the *break* keyword to have it remove all matches.

```java
public static void removeGame(String name){
    for (Game game : gameList) {
        if (game.getName().equals(name)) {
            gameList.remove(game);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Output

```
[Call of Duty:300, Last day on Earth:500, Fall Guys:3000]
[Call of Duty:300, Last day on Earth:500]
```

Furthermore, there is a semantic error on line 38.

```java
if(gameList.indexOf(gameList.contains(name)) >= 0)
```

Again, you'll want to iterate on *gameList* and check for a match.

```java
public static boolean findGame(String name){
    // check if the game is in the LinkedList
    for (Game game : gameList) {
        if (game.getName().equals(name)) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```